# What is the expected request to get GoToWebinar webinar details based on organiser_key?

Tags: rest, integration

I am trying to fetch GoToWebinar details via the

Get Webinars method
​/organizers​/{organizerKey}​/webinars
 listed on the GoToWebinar API reference.

I'm passing the below body:

```
{
"fromTime":"2015-07-13T10:00:00Z",
"toTime":"2015-07-13T22:00:00Z"
}
```

But in response, I get the below error:

```
{
"errorId": "26a9b9a8-3a92-45b0-acdd-7ac3c3f485ac",
"requestId": null,
"timeStamp": 1587960550357,
"reason": "invalid.data",
"errorCode": "invalid.data",
**"description": "Required DateTime parameter 'fromTime' is not present",**
"incident": "5801952841989547523",
"details": null
}
```

The API reference guide does not specify any request structure, just mentions what is needed to be sent, and I have built my logic on the same. Yet I am unable to get a proper response.

Can anybody help me in understanding what the expected request should be?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a GET HTTP call you can not add these parameters to the **Body**. I mean you can but it won't be sent along with the call (only with POST/PUT). So you should add the two fields you provided to the **Query Parameters** instead.